# How can I list WooCommerce orders ( WC_Order ) of certain WC_Customer?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

With WooCommerce 2.4.13, I would like to obtain a list of orders ( `WC_Order` ) of certain customers ( `WC_Customer` , not only the current logged-in customer ). From the [documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/class-reference/), the class `WC_Customer` has no public property / function to access associated order records.

How can I achieve this? the only solution I can think of is to fetch the raw data from the database. Any better solution?

*p.s. It seems it's difficult to obtain the list of WooCommerce customers as well.*

Comment: Instead of fetching raw data from the database, you can craft your own `WP_Query` and get the required results. `shop_orders` is a custom post type, and the customer to which the order belongs to is stored as post meta in the `_customer_user` key.

Comment: very nice suggestion indeed. Where can I find more WooCommerce CPT information? I may need it in further development.

Comment: CPT is a WordPress feature, you can read about it here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types

Comment: Yes I know. Is there a list of CPT names that WooCommerce use? Thanks

Comment: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Comment: @Raptor: May the below answer can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get order for a specific customer as follows:

```
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => $user->ID,
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) );
```

Where `$user->ID` is the user id of the customer for whom you want to fetch order.

Hope this helps.